# My android widget crashes launcher. How do I debug that?

Tags: android, debugging, crash, android-widget, android-launcher

I have developed a simple widget which has two buttons switching my dual-sim phone sim cards on and off. I wire buttons click within onUpdate method of my AppWidgetProvider implementation. Unfortinately after few successfull clicks, launcher reloads(I observe short blink on my device screen) and my widget no longer does anything on button clicks.

I tried to look at my LogCat but didn't find anything interesting for the launcher app there.

Now the question is how do I debug such situation?

edit:
Here is some code of my AppWidgetProvider. I understand that the code is naive and needs some refactoring, but I still need to debug that launcher crash somehow:

```
    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    ComponentName widget;

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    widget = new ComponentName(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);

    int currentState = Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "dual_sim_mode_setting", -1);
    String sim1Text = currentState == 1 || currentState == 3 ? "on" : "off";
    String sim2Text = currentState == 2 || currentState == 3 ? "on" : "off";

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.first_button, sim1Text);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.second_button, sim2Text);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.first_button, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SIM1_CLICKED));
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.second_button, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SIM2_CLICKED));
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widget, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE".equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        return;
    }

    if (SIM1_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        switchSim(1, context);
        return;
    }

    else if (SIM2_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        switchSim(2, context);
    }

    else if ("android.intent.action.DUAL_SIM_MODE".equals(intent.getAction())){
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);

        int mode = intent.getIntExtra("mode", -1);
        switch (mode)
            {
                case 0:
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.first_button, "off");
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.second_button, "off");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.first_button, "on");
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.second_button, "off");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.first_button, "off");
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.second_button, "on");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.first_button, "on");
                    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.second_button, "on");
                    break;
            }

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm since you didn't post any code I can only guess but I assume you implemented a `View.OnClickListener`. I would simply do the following:

Declare a tag for debugging:

```
final String tag = "#OnClick";
```

Log infos:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(tag, "I've been clicked!") // or even add useful information.
            // code ..
        }
    });
```

That way you could at least make sure to see whether the `OnClickListener` still gets called on your buttons.

In order to see the messages you could add a filter to your logCat like so:

[image]

At least this is how LogCat works in Eclipse, I'm not sure about other APIs but there's probably something similar.